# If $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ so $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Prove that:
$$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$$
I tried Rearrangement, uvw, BW and more, but without any success.

Comment: why should this help?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Have you considered bounding the $3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$ term w.r.t. the $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3$ condition and then squeezing with a slightly stronger inequality?

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg I tried. This inequality is very strong and I think we must use here strong methods. uvw for example. I lost here.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If we think about a cube with side lengths $x = a^2, y = b^2$ and $z = c^2$ we can bound the volume of the cube under the plane $x + y + z - 3 = 0$ via lagrange multipliers and then prove a slightly different inequality, would you agree?

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg This inequality is cyclic and not symmetric. I think, Lagrange multipliers method does not help here. It's impossible to solve  the system, which we get. I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Leftrightarrow (a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)^2 \ge 9(abc)^{4/3}=3(abc)^{4/3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

$$\sum_{cyc}a^4b^2+2\sum_{cyc}a^3bc^2 \ge 3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a^{10}b^4c^4}$$

By AM-GM : 
$$a^4b^2+2a^3bc^2 \ge 3\sqrt[3]{a^{10}b^4c^4}$$